# Apache serving wrong VirtualHost

Tags: apache-http-server, centos-7

I want to show you something very strage, found on a Centos7 server with Apache `httpd`:

If I visit one domain from the same machine, I'm served by the right virtualhost:

```
wget http://foo-test.cloud -O -

-> Welcome in Foo Test.cloud!
```

Anyway if I visit that same domain from the WAN, I'm served by the wrong virtualhost:

```
wget http://foo-test.cloud -O -

-> Welcome in awesome.com!
```

This is what Apache understand from my configuration files (the output of `httpd -S`):

```
# httpd -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server ewm-dummy-default
         port 80 namevhost dummy-default
         port 80 namevhost awesome.com
         port 80 namevhost foo-test.cloud
```

As you can see, the strange part is that the domain name is correct and that the default website is not one of these domains.

What the hell may be? I'm open to whatever suggestion.

---

Notes:

- When visiting from localhost the server prints the access log line
- When visiting from the Internet the server DOES NOT print any log line

Additional Notes:

- I tested with `tcpdump` and I was able to see the incoming requests to port 80 in both cases. Both with the right `Host:` HTTP header.
- I see the `httpd` process listening to `:::80` with `netstat`

---

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Does the machine on the WAN have a hosts entry that is pointing to a different machine than the one you think it is?

Comment: Nope, but I noticed that the server was not aware of its public IP address (because there is an Azure hardware firewall in front of it I think - maybe this is part of the problem). Anyway, with `tcpdump` on the server, I see that the server is reached by these HTTP WAN requests.

Comment: So did that take care of it?

Comment: @Dave Yep, the webserver is reached by both the LAN and WAN requests and the HTTP headers are preserved.

Comment: Damn it. I figure out the problem. That was caused by a legacy `iptables` rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you have this weird situation:

- `tcpdump` sees the incoming connections on the port `:80` and nothing is missed
- apache listening on port `:80` lot logging *some* incoming requests

Please check your `iptables` rules. In my case, I had this situation:

```
# iptables -t nat -L -n -v

 3418  150K REDIRECT   tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            10.0.1.4             tcp dpt:80 redir ports 8080
```

So it seems that on this webserver (that is `10.0.1.4`) was setup a low-level legacy port forwarding from port `:80` to port `:8080` to expose a Tomcat webserver. Deleting that legacy iptable rule fixed the problem.

That's why Apache was not logging something: Apache was sometime not reached by its port.

The troubleshooting may be not easy because the purpose of Apache, often, is to act as a frontend webserver for other internal webservers, so that's why from just the response body you may be not able to distinguish one webserver from another one, because their response sometime should be the same.

Also note that connections from localhost may come from the IPv6 loopback interface (`::1`) that does not match that iptables rule. That's why the different behaviours.

Hoping that this may be useful to some other people to save time in troubleshooting very weird problems, the short answer is: look at legacy iptable rules.